# Change css class element height in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, css

Dear Fellow programmers

I am working on a project, that has minimized versions of amChart JavaScript files in it. The problem is I need to change a height of a specific class element in those JS files. However, they are minimized. So I cant really change anything about them.

I got an idea of crating a new JS file, change the height attribute of that class, and place it in the resources page under the other amchart minimized JavaScript files, that way it could read my JS at the end and place the height attribute that I need, since I believe the way it works is it reads the JS files in order.

In case you are wondering why don't I just make a CSS file instead of a JavaScript file is because JS files are read after CSS files so it does not matter where I place it.

Can you tell me if that is how we change a height attribute for a class element in a JavaScript file ? the class is .amchartsLegend

```
//changing the height attribute of amChartsLegend

var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".amChartsLegend")
myElement.style.height("20px")
```

One more question is should document be replaced by the actual name of the amchart minimized JS file ? assuming that's the correct code for changing the height

Comment: querySelectorAll does not work like JQuery and you will have to manually loop over the returned elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Javascript, why don't you override the style instead?

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .amChartsLegend {
        height: 20px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: because I tried that already. I placed it in the html file everywhere. it even showed it was under the deferred resources, nothing changed with the height though. I did not add !important but I am assuming that's not necessary.

Comment: @Mozein - You must use `!important` because the other minified styles may contain selectors with a higher specificity... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: The `!important` modifier will override any previous defined property.

Comment: you were right. !important was the problem.  This worked !!
 Thank you LcSlazar

Comment: LOL it's supposed was a javascript issue

Answer (score 2):

Use the [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) since you are using the [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) it returns an array

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".amChartsLegend");
console.log(myElements.length);
for (var i= 0; i < myElements.length ; i++) { 
   myElements[i].style.height = "20px"
}
```

here is an example

```js
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".amChartsLegend");
console.log(myElements.length);
for (var i= 0; i < myElements.length ; i++) { 
   myElements[i].style.height = "20px"
}
```

```css
memu li{
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li class=amChartsLegend>amChartsLegend</li>
  <li>normal</li>
  <li class=amChartsLegend>amChartsLegend</li>
  <li class=amChartsLegend>amChartsLegend</li>
  <li>normal</li>
  <li>normal</li>
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. It turned out I can solve it with css file but this helped me understand well how to include css in a javascript file

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".amChartsLegend")
for (var i =0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.height = "20px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".amChartsLegend");
for (var i= 0; i < myElements.lenght ; i++) { 
myElement[i].style.height="20px";
}
```

Comment: @felipsmartins: it was a typo error...changed it..thanks for pointing it out :)